# Custom Claim Types

Tags: claims-based-auth, claims, claim-provider

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx defines custom claims, but I am just dense or missing something that appears to be obvious..

In the first code section,
What is "http://example.org/claims/simplecustomclaim" supposed to be?

Just that simple link even if it does not exist as a real page. I've been doing a bit of searching and I can't find an explanation of what the URL for the custom claim actually is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare that with a namespace in code. You should have something that is unique enough for your deployment, so that it does not collide with other claims providers.

If you have a domain name that you own, you can use that as the base url and then add `/claims/yourclaimsname` at the end